# TargetInvocationException when instantiating object implementing IEMDKListener

Tags: motorola-emdk

I am trying to use the component "EMDK for Xamarin" published by Zebra in the Xamarin Component store.

Per the sample, I am implementing the `EMDKManager.IEMDKListener` interface on a class I've created.

When I instantiate the class, I get a `Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exception listed as the InnerException inside the `TargetInvocationException` exception being thrown.

When I try to step into the class constructor for the class I created, I noticed it crashes before the first line is executed.

Has anyone else experienced this runtime exception before? How do I avoid the `NoClassDefFoundError` exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into that same error. The fix was adding a few attributes in my `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. The attributes allow the low level access to the EMDK installed on the device.

`[assembly: Android.App.UsesLibrary(Name = "com.symbol.emdk")]
[assembly: Android.App.UsesPermission(Name = "com.symbol.emdk.permission.EMDK")]`